# how to set up this relationship in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have table `staff` with fields `id` and `initials`.

Related table `sales` has fields `seller`, and `lister` - both these should point to the `initials` in the `staff` table.

So in the sales table, there can be a different staff member who was the seller to the staff member who was the lister - that is the relation i'm trying to implement.

I'm not sure i can find this kind of thing in the docs.

In the `Sales` model, rules method I have:

```
[['lister'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Staff::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['lister' => 'id']],
[['seller'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Staff::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['seller' => 'id']],
```

However, when I try to display the relationship in the gridview via `staff.initials`, I'm getting exception

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\Sale::staff
```

I'm sure i'm not representing the relationship correctly somewhere, or is there a flaw in my db design ?

Comment: Show us the corresponding relations in your Sale class

Comment: What i have is above in the sales model.  Is there something I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

First off it sounds like your data model is flawed. The only reason I say this is because it may influence what correction you need to bring to your code.

The Issue here is that several staff members may have the same set of initials in which case you'll never know who your `sales` table is referring to. I suggest you keep the `staff.id` in the `seller` and `lister` fields (instead of `initials`)

If we can agree on the above then it sounds like you're missing a relationship in your `Sales` model. Check the [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data).

You'll need to add the following methods to your `Sales` model:

```
public function getSeller()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['id' => 'seller']);
}

public function getLister()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['id' => 'lister']);
}
```

Once this is done you'll be able to access these via:

```
$sale = Sales::find()->one();
$sale->lister; // will return a Staff object.
$sale->seller; // will return a Staff object.
```

In a gridView you should be able to display the initials with `seller.initials` and/or `lister.initials`.

Let me know if that works for you.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but now I dont get the error, in the gridview it says "(not set)" ?

Comment: are the initials in the DB? can you show your gridview call in a gist?

Comment: When constructing the query used with the dataprovider are you perhaps missing `->with('staff')` ? example: `Sales::find()->with('staff')->all()`. Though I thought it wasn't mandatory.

Comment: is the dataprovider from the SaleSearch model ? If so, I used Gii to generate it and no, it doesn't have the with('staff') - although I just tried it and then it said there was no Staff relation

Comment: sorry my bad I ment with('lister') and with ('seller'). I'm finding the not set error a little odd. It usually means the field is set to NULL.. But I'm guessing seller/lister have a value of 1 (or any other existing row) so it should work.